# Hortonworks VM - Hadoop batch upload?

Tags: hadoop, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

Is there a way to batch upload files to Hadoop under a Hortonworks VM running CentOS? I see I can use the Ambari - Sandbox's HDFS Files tool, but that only allows uploading one-by-one. Apparently you could use [Redgate's HDFS Explorer](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/use-hdfs-explorer-manage-files-hortonworks-sandbox/) in the past, but it's no longer available. Hadoop is made to process big data, but it's absurd having to upload all files one-by-one...
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can use the `*` wildcard in `copyFromLocal`, f.e.:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal input/* /tmp/input
```